# [filepond]To register with the ID value serverId received from the server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filepond

'filepond' is being used in vue. But there's a problem.
In "process",
The ID value was returned after the file was transferred to the server. (response.id) If you register this as 'serverId' of file and check 'file' as console, it is registered normally.

```
  mounted() {
setOptions({
  server: {
    process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('mainData', file);
      createmainData(formData, {
        onUploadProgress: (event) => {
          progress(event.lengthComputable, event.loaded, event.total);
        }
    })
      .then(response => {
        const serverId = response.id
        file.serverId = serverId
        load(response, serverId)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        error('Error uploading file');
      })
      console.log (file)
    },
  },
});
}
```

[image]

But if you run 'updatefiles' methods and check 'files' as a console,
It says 'serverId: undefined'.

```
    methods: {
  updatefiles(files) {
    this.files = files.map(files => files.setMetadata);
    console.log('files',files )
  },
},
```

[image]

If you look at the comments left by the producers,

[image]
I tried, but I keep failing, maybe I'm misunderstanding.
Can you tell me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to push serverId to separate array (i.e. uploadedFiles) in the process after the file was successfully transfered to the server. I can't see this in your code. With this array you will be able to manage FilePond content and order of uploaded files.

```
handleFilePondInit() {
    this.uploadedFiles = [];
},

handleFilePondLoad(response) {
   this.uploadedFiles.push(response);
   return response;
},

handleFilePondUpdate(files, origin, target) {
    this.uploadedFiles = files.map(files => files.serverId);
    this.uploadedFiles = this.uploadedFiles.filter(element => { return element !== null; });
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
It wasn't the answer I wanted, but I solved it!
All I had to do was get the 'objectId' value returned from the server as 'serverId'.
//solution// createmainData(formData, {
onUploadProgress: (event) => {progress(event.lengthComputable, event.loaded, event.total)}})
.then(serverId => {load(serverId)})